IPFS Integration
I've mashed IPFS up with Stellar to mail DAG roots between accounts in transaction memos, and to post mutable links to them in account data. It also derives encryption keys from a signature and ciphers data if keys are available. Is anyone interested in a port of this to Solana? Do you want to read a document about what I did? I would have just posted the document link but I don't want to spam this board if there's no interest. BE

This isn't the right forum to promote your project, but you can maybe bring it up at https://forum.solana.com
